# Trigonometric sum asymptotic (Titchmarsh, Lemma 4.7, p74)

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, trigonometric-series, trigonometric-integrals

> **Lemma 4.7: (p74)** Let $f(x)$ be a real function with a continuous and steadily increasing derivative $f'(x)$ in $(a,b)$, and let $f'(b) = \alpha$, $f'(a) = \beta.$ Then, $$ \sum_{a < n \le b } e^{2 \pi i f(n) } = \sum_{\alpha - \eta < \nu < \beta + \eta} \int_a^b e^{2 \pi i (f(x) - \nu x ) } \, dx  + O\{ \log (\beta - \alpha + 2 ) \}, $$
> where $\eta$ is any positive constant less than $1$. (The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-function, Titchmarsh)

The text proves the following two results:

> 1. By making change of variables $h(x)=f(x)-kx$ , we may assume wlog $\eta -1 < \alpha \le \eta.$
> 2. $$ \sum_{a < n \le b } e^{2 \pi i f(n) } = \sum_{\alpha - \eta < \nu < \beta + \eta} \int_a^b e^{2 \pi i (f(x) - \nu x ) } \, dx +O(\log (\beta+2)) + O(1). $$
>    "The result therefore follows".

My question is what happened to "$ \beta - \alpha+2$" in the original expression? Why does "the theorem follows" - or is there a typo?

Comment: Look at $\int_a^{b+1} e^{2i \pi f(\lfloor x \rfloor )}dx$. More generally, at the [EMSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula). And you can link to Titchmarsh's [book](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Titchmarsh_TheTheoryoftheRiemannZeta-Function.pdf) (p.42).

Comment: In fact he is using Fourier series and Dirichlet kernel, see lemma 4.2

Comment: What I mean is, is what he proved equivalent to the theorem? He proved $O \{ \log (\beta+2) \}$ instead of $O \{ \log ( \beta - \alpha+2) \}. $

Comment: This is trivial.

Comment: I'm sorry, may you explain why? :(

Comment: Are you kidding ?

Comment: I'm sorry reuns if this is trivial, but may you just explain a little on why we have $O(\beta-\alpha+2)$ instead of $O(\beta+2)$? I believe they are equivalent. But what is the reason of the choice?