# Asymptotics relation on logarithm

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

> Given $\alpha, \beta, \eta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that  $\eta - 1 <
>  \alpha \le \eta$, $0 < \eta < 1$, and $\beta \ge \alpha $. Is it true
>    that $$\log (\beta+2) = O \{ \log ( \beta - \alpha+2 ) \} ?$$

Thoughts:

If $\alpha <  0$ then $\log ( \beta +2 ) \le \log ( \beta - \alpha +2 )$. If $0 \le \alpha < 1$, then by taylor expansion about $\beta - \alpha+2$, we have 
$$ \log ( \beta +2 ) = \log ( \beta - \alpha+2) + \alpha \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-\alpha)^{k-1}}{(\beta - \alpha+2)^{k-1}} \frac{1 }{k}. $$

But the series 
$$ \alpha \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-\alpha)^{k-1}}{(\beta - \alpha+2)^{k-1}} \frac{1 }{k} = O(1). $$ 
 is independent of $\alpha, \beta$ as $\{ \Big| \frac{\alpha}{\beta- \alpha+2} \Big| , | \alpha|  \} < 1$, and we can bound the sum above and below by the first or the first two terms. Thus, we have, 
$$ \log ( \beta +2 ) = O( \log ( \beta - \alpha+2 ) )$$ 
for all $\alpha < 1 $.

EDIT: A proof inspired from Peter.

Let $g(\beta) = \log(\beta+2) - \log(b-\alpha+2)$. Then $g(\beta) \rightarrow 0$ as $\beta \rightarrow \infty$. So exists $N$ such that for all $\beta > N$, $|g(\beta)|<S_1$. And for $ \beta \in [0,N]$, $|g(\beta)| < S_2$ as we have a continuous function on a compact set. 
Thus, 
$$ |g(\beta)| < \max \{ S_1, S_2 \}. $$ 
and the claim follows(?)

Comment: If $\beta$ tends to $\infty$ , even the expression $$\log(\beta+\alpha)-\log(\beta+\gamma)$$ tends to $0$ for every fixed real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$. This implies your claim.

Comment: Peter, I edited my post - is that what you mean? Also, you mind having a look at this post, as this was where the question originally come from: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373782/trigonometric-sum-asymptotic-titchmarsh-lemma-4-7-p74

Comment: slightly different ; Since $\log(\beta+\alpha)$ and $\log(\beta+\gamma)$ both tend to $\infty$ and the difference tends to $0$, we can conclude that the ration tends to $1$, which is what we need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we have $$\lim_{\beta\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log(\beta+\alpha)}{\log{(\beta+\gamma})}=\lim_{\beta\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log(\beta)+\log(1+\frac{\alpha}{\beta})}{\log(\beta)+\log(1+\frac{\gamma}{\beta})}=1$$ since $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ and $\frac{\gamma}{\beta}$ both tend to $0$

This implies your claim.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks a lot. So in the theorem I linked ( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373782/trigonometric-sum-asymptotic-titchmarsh-lemma-4-7-p74) are $O(\log \beta - \alpha+2)$ and $O(\log \beta)$ interchangeable? Or is there something different to this?

Comment: No. The expressions are interchangeable because your claim holds which is a special case of my more general claim. And my comments above also justify the $O(1)$-term.

Comment: Ok, I should have read this earlier. So you mean the two expressions are interchangeble  - but then why express in terms of $O\{ \log (\beta - \alpha+2) \}$ rather than $O \{ \log (\beta +2 ) \}$?

Comment: No idea. Probably comes somehow from some theorem with an $O$-term.